# Sentry --rewrite option failing command

Tags: circleci, sentry

I am looking at improving a `CI` process by rewriting source maps, and found I can not add the `--rewrite` option in anywhere.

The command I am adding it to is:

> sentry-cli --auth-token $SENTRY_TOKEN releases -o "my-org" files $LONG_COMMIT upload my_repo/my_files '~/my_public_folder'

No matter where I place it I always get the error:

> error: Found argument '--rewrite' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
> USAGE:
> sentry-cli releases files upload [OPTIONS]  [--] [NAME]

For example I have tried:

> sentry-cli --auth-token $SENTRY_TOKEN releases -o "my-org" files $LONG_COMMIT upload my_repo/my_files '~/my_public_folder' --rewrite

> sentry-cli --auth-token $SENTRY_TOKEN releases -o "my-org" files $LONG_COMMIT upload my_repo/my_files --rewrite '~/my_public_folder'

> sentry-cli --auth-token $SENTRY_TOKEN releases -o "my-org" files $LONG_COMMIT upload  --rewrite my_repo/my_files '~/my_public_folder'

Comment: this parameter is on by default on the latest versions of sentry-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--rewrite` option is not available for `sentry-cli releases files upload`. I believe that you're looking for the `sentry-cli releases files upload-sourcemaps` command, instead.

Note that as of [sentry-cli 1.59.0](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#sentry-cli-1590) the `--rewrite` option has been removed and enabled by default. You can opt out of rewriting using the `--no-rewrite` option:

```
 $ sentry-cli releases files upload-sourcemaps --help
Upload sourcemaps for a release.

USAGE:
    sentry-cli releases files <VERSION> upload-sourcemaps [OPTIONS] <PATHS>...

OPTIONS:
...
        --no-rewrite
            Disables rewriting of matching sourcemaps. By default the tool will rewrite sources, so
            that indexed maps are flattened and missing sources are inlined if possible.
            This fundamentally changes the upload process to be based on sourcemaps and minified
            files exclusively and comes in handy for setups like react-native that generate
            sourcemaps that would otherwise not work for sentry.
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct - my bad. This has solved my problem.